# Возможно ли хранить поля класса в строковом виде?

Tags: c++

Добрый день.

Есть ли возможность подставлять к имени объекта поля, хранящегося в строковом виде, вообщем так

```
class Data
{
    Data(int a, char *s)
    {
        value a;
        str = s;
    }

 private:
    int value;
    char *str;
}

main()
{
    Data ob(99, "Hellon");

    char *poleclassaint = "valuen";
    char *poleclassachar = "strn";

    cout << ob.poleclassaint;   // 99
    cout << ob.poleclassachar;  // Hello

}
```

На С++ давно не программировал, может что-то неправильно, пишу на Objective C, но если в С++ так можно или как-нибудь иначе, то думаю и в Objective C можно так. Главное позволит ли компилятор такое. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection, Luke!

В C++ подобное возможно с использованием метаобъектной системы Qt. Для Вашего примера будет примерно так (в классе Data оставил одну приватную переменную).

Класс Data (data.h):

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

#include <QObject>

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int value READ value WRITE setValue)
public:
    // Конструкторы
    explicit Data(QObject *parent = 0);
    Data(int a);

    // Функция-getter свойства value
    int value() const;

public slots:
    // Функция-setter свойства value
    void setValue(int &v);

private:
    int m_value;
};

#endif // DATA_H
```

Реализация методов класса Data (data.cpp):

```
#include "data.h"

Data::Data(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

Data::Data(int a)
{
    m_value = a;
}

int Data::value() const
{
    return m_value;
}

void Data::setValue(int &v)
{
    m_value = v;
}
```

Тестовая программа (main.cpp)

```
#include <QVariant>
#include "data.h"

int main()
{
    // Строка с именем свойства, к которому мы хотим получить доступ
    const char *propertyName = QString("value").toLatin1().constData();

    // В конструкторе инициализируем свойство value значением 99
    Data testInstance(99);

    // Устанавливаем новое значение свойства value в 150
    testInstance.setProperty(propertyName, QVariant(150));

    // Тестовый вывод, чтобы убедиться, что значение свойства изменилось
    qDebug("%d", testInstance.value());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

На Objective-C не пишу, но википедия относит его к [reflective programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reflective_programming_languages_and_platforms). Так что механизмы должны быть.

Comment: stringly-typed language :-)

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, C++ этого делать не позволяет. Классы в C++ должны быть полностью определены на этапе компиляции программы, и это архитектурная особенность языка.

Если вы хотите смоделировать класс с переменным составом полей (свойств), то придется пользоваться, например, ассоциативным контейнером вариативных данных (`std::map` +  `boost::any`).

Comment: Если вы хотите смоделировать класс с переменным составом полей (свойств), то придется пользоваться, например, ассоциативным контейнером вариативных данных (std::map + boost::any).

А можно поподробней?

Answer (score 0):

Такое и на Objective-C не отработает.

```
[ob valueForKey:@"value"];
```

А если вам нужно на плюсах именно таком виде, то помимо полей класса прийдется хранить еще и словарь (по типу NSDictionary) и реализовывать какой-то метод доступа, в котором будете выдирать значения из словаря.